# Google ml-engine: takes forever to fill the queue

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I have created `tf records` files that are stored on a google storage bucket. I have a code running on ml-engine to train a model using the data in these `tf records`

Each tf record file contains a batch of 20 examples and is approximately 8Mb size (*Mega* bytes). There are several thousands of files on the bucket.

My problem is that it litteraly takes forever to start the training. I have to wait about 40 minutes between the moment where the package is loaded and the moment where the training actually starts. I am guessing this is the time necessary to download the data and fill the queues?

The code is (slightly simplified for sake of conciseness):

```
    # Create a queue which will produce tf record names
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(files, num_epochs=num_epochs, capacity=100)

    # Read the record
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)

    # Map for decoding the serialized example
    features = tf.parse_single_example(
        serialized_example,
        features={
            'data': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32),
            'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
        })

    train_tensors = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
        [features['data'], features['label']],
        batch_size=30,
        capacity=600,
        min_after_dequeue=400,
        allow_smaller_final_batch=True
        enqueue_many=True)
```

I have checked that my bucket and my job share the same `region` parameter.

I don't understand what is taking so long: it should just be a matter of downloading a few hundreds Mbs (a few tens of tf records files should be enough to have more than `min_after_dequeue` elements in the queue).

Any idea of what am I missing, or where the problem might be?

Thanks

Comment: What --runtime-version are you using? I recommend using TF 1.4 (just barely released). Have you tried running locally while loading the data from GCS? If that's possible in your case, please report how long it takes locally.

Comment: Barely released from yesterday? Because I tried 2 days ago and I could not run with --runtime-version 1.4. Anyway, I observe the same behaviour with TF 1.4. However I think I have found the problem (see answer), so I will shamefully close the question

Comment: TF 1.4 is unofficially available as of yesterday. We believe there might be a bug in TF itself, so need to resolve that before making it official.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, my bad. I was using a custom function to:

1. Verify that each file passed as a tf record actually exists.
2. Expand wild-card characters, if any

Turns out this is a *very* bad idea when dealing with thousands of files on gs://

I have removed this "sanity" check and it's  working fine now.

Comment: Glad to hear you discovered the issue!